# Are the inmates in the "Phantom Zone" able to touch one another?

Tags: dc, superman

While imprisoned in the Phantom Zone, can the inmates touch one another? To clarify, I know they can see each other and communicate, but are they disembodied phantoms to each other, or do they have the ability to make physical contact with one another within the zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** No. They are unable to interact with each other or the world around them. They can communicate with each other telepathically.

### References

**Pre-Crisis DC Universe**

[Wikipedia Reference:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_Zone)

> The Phantom Zone was discovered by Jor-El and used on the planet
>   Krypton as a method of imprisoning criminals. Previously, criminals
>   were punished by being sealed into capsules and rocketed into orbit in
>   suspended animation with crystals attached to their foreheads to
>   slowly erase their criminal tendencies; Klax-Ar was one criminal who
>   received this punishment but escaped. Gra-Mo was the last to suffer
>   the punishment, for it was then abolished in favor of the Phantom
>   Zone, which was considered more humane and cost-efficient, but an
>   equally effective punishment. The Phantom Zone criminals first
>   appeared in Adventure Comics (Superboy stories), and soon began
>   appearing in Superman stories. The inmates of the Phantom Zone reside
>   in a featureless state of existence from which they can observe, but
>   cannot interact with, the regular universe. **Inmates do not age or
>   require sustenance in the Phantom Zone; furthermore, they are
>   telepathic and mutually insubstantial.** (Emphasis is mine.)
>
> Post-Crisis In the post-Crisis DC Universe, the Phantom Zone first
>   appears after Superman returns from space with a Kryptonian artifact
>   called the Eradicator. This device, created by his Kryptonian ancestor
>   Kem-L, attempts to recreate Krypton on Earth, building the Fortress of
>   Solitude; the extradimensional space in which the Eradicator finds the
>   Kryptonian materials necessary is called the Phantom Zone.[2][3] A
>   Phantom Zone Projector is part of Superman's current Fortress. It has
>   been used to access the Bottle City of Kandor and to trap villains
>   such as the White Martians.
>
> The Phantom Zone has been independently discovered by the Bgztlians,
>   the White Martians, and the villains Loophole, Prometheus, and the
>   first Queen Bee, who call it the "Buffer Zone", the "Still Zone", the
>   "Stasis Zone", the "Ghost Zone", and the "Honeycomb", respectively. In
>   post-Crisis/post-Zero Hour continuity, it was Loophole's "Stasis Zone"
>   technology that exiled Mon-El, known in the new continuity as
>   Valor/M'Onel, into the Phantom Zone for a thousand years.
>
> It is inferred that the prisoners suffer the same insubstantial nature
>   as the Pre-Crisis Phantom Zone.